# Select `li` of `nav > ul`

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select the elements `li`, children of the element `nav > ul`?

As you can see in the following snippet, I can select `nav > ul` and remove the listing style. However, I can't manage to change the color of only `Link1`, `Link2` and `Link3`.

```css
nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul li {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Link1
        </li>
        <li>
            Link2
        </li>
        <li>
            Link3
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Link3-1
                </li>
                <li>
                    Link3-1
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The answer `nav > ul > li` does not work, according to [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sosnLg5z/1/). To people down voting the question, could you *at least* provide a reason?

Comment: Where did you find that `>` in your example `nav > ul` ? You can look these things up... Don't blindly copy it. Find out what it means.

Comment: Where did you find that I copied it? I wrote it myself, according to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp .

Comment: People are assuming you blindly copied it because it's doubtful that you can write a selector like `nav > ul` yourself but not know to apply it to something like `ul > li`. In fact, I'd like to assume otherwise, and that you simply discovered that it does not work for other reasons but have simply neglected to mention this crucial detail from the get-go.

Answer (score 1):

There are four different combinators in CSS3, in this situation we used two of them:

***Descendant Selector*** (selectors separated by 'space')

***Child Selector*** (selectors separated by '>')

So ***"nav > ul > li"*** (select the four LI presents on the first UL), 
and then applies the color red, consequently all text color becomes red.

*As the second UL is a child of fourth LI it gets red too.*

To fix that we need create a rule for all the subsequent UL's.

```
nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li { /* only direct children */
    color: red;
}

nav > ul ul { color: black; } // resets the color of the nested ULs
```

Comment: Could you explain how/why your code works? That'll enable the OP and others to understand and apply your methods (where applicable) elsewhere. Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/284827) and liable to be deleted. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10378636)

Answer (score 0):

Give them class names like:

```
<li class = "red_font">
```

then change your CSS to:

```
.red_font{
 color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code ran, I think the li inside that parent li element inherit the color thus the color goes to all li elements.

I'd suggest you specify with another selector like id or class to make it easier to specify the elements you want to manipulate.

```css
nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul > li {
    color: red;
}

li > ul li{
  color: black;
 }
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Link1
        </li>
        <li>
            Link2
        </li>
        <li>
            Link3
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Link3-1
                </li>
                <li>
                    Link3-1
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to achieve what you want, here is another way which is not yet presented in the other answers:

add a class "skip" to the `li` which contains the 2nd level of links, and skip it in your css using the `:not` selector:

```css
nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li:not(.skip) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Link1
        </li>
        <li>
            Link2
        </li>
        <li>
            Link3
        </li>
        <li class="skip">
            <ul >
                <li>
                    Link3-1
                </li>
                <li>
                    Link3-1
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you're selecting every children. See the solution below:

```css
nav > ul {
    list-style: none; /* This will disable listing styles */
}

nav > ul > li {
    color: red; /* this will select Link1, Link2 and Link3 (first level) */
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
    color: #000; /* this will select Link3-1 and Link3-2 (second level) */
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Link1
        </li>
        <li>
            Link2
        </li>
        <li>
            Link3
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Link3-1
                </li>
                <li>
                    Link3-2
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```